# agvtool new-marketing-version doesn't work on Xcode 13

Tags: xcode, xcode13, agvtool

Since Xcode 13, there is no `Info.plist` by default. Instead, the common field are in the target’s Info tab, and build settings in the project editor. A separated `Info.plist` file is added to project only when there are additional fields.

When I run the following command to set MARKETING_VERSION on Jenkins

```bash
$ xcrun agvtool new-marketing-version 1.0.0
```

It doesn't have any effect on `Info.plist` file unless the key `CFBundleShortVersionString` exists. But every time I update field in target's Info tab, the `Info.plist` file seems to be regenerated again and `CFBundleShortVersionString` disappear.

Therefore, **I'm wondering is there any suggestion about how to setting `MARKETING_VERSION` via command line or how to use agvtool in this case. Any suggestion would be appreciated!**

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same issue and so far could not figure out what makes Xcode regenerate the plist file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, in Xcode 13 agvtool has trouble to update marketing version.
In order to "fix" it, set `GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE` to NO in `Build settings`. This will prevent Xcode to generate the Info.plist automatically. Then create your own Info.plist with the same values and it should works.

Maxime

Comment: The problem is that even if you set `GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE` to NO, `MARKETING_VERSION` is no longer in the `Info.plist` file, but in the project file and so does not get updated.

Comment: add Info.plist, copy values from generated to new,add path to the new Info.plist in build settings,generate plist -> NO, make sure you are not copying it to target (because it is processed and than copied, you would have error that it is done twice), than xcrun agvtool new-marketing-version 1.2.3 <-new test version works, it does update correct field.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE` to NO in Build settings, it will throw you the next error: `Cannot find "ABC.xcodeproj/../NO` when using agvtool to update the marketing version. The only way I could find to fix this was to manually delete from `project.pbxproj` all the `GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE` lines.